# Why does this chained :not selector not work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a child div which has been effected by .img class.

Although I insert `:not` selector for this div as

```
.main .content .index-exp .img:not(#view-image):not(.view-image){ /*rest*/ }
```

it is still effecting my div and this hurts my brain.

If I remove `:not(#view-image)` it is working as expected,

but as `.img:not(#view-image):not(.view-image)` chained not working.

I know that this kind of usage is true.

What could be problem.

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/x80vm7y8/6/ address.

My result

[image]

Expected result is

[image]

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="index-exp">
<div class="container">
<div class="viewers">
    <div class="product-exp">
        <div class="view-exp">      
            <div class="content">
                <div class="inquiry-form">
                    <form action="http://akasiayachting.com/wp-content/themes/active3/php/get_sendmail/get_sendmail.php" method="post" name="inquiry-form">
                        <div>
                            <span class="img"><img class="view-image" id="captcha" src="http://akasiayachting.com/wp-content/themes/active3/php/get_captcha/get_captcha.php" /></span>
                            <span class="img"><img class="view-image" id="code-refresh" src="http://akasiayachting.com/wp-content/themes/active3/views/active-71-detail/images/form-icon-refresh.png" /></span>
                            <input name="code-verification" type="text" class="code-verification" value="Security Code" />
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Inquiry" />
                        </div>
                    </form><!-- #form -->
                </div><!-- #inquiry-form -->
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #view-exp -->
    </div><!-- #product-exp -->
    </div><!-- #viewers -->    
</div><!-- #container -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like `.view-image` is only on the `img` tag and not on the `.img` class and there isn't even a `#view-image`. It would help if you can simplify this a bit, even the amount of css in the fiddle is hard to go through

Comment: A **reduced** example would make it easier to look through the code.

Comment: I wonder if combining the 2 `:not`s into one would work.  `.img:not(#view-image,.view-image)`

Comment: @Huangism  If I remove line 69 it is working as expected. .img class is effecting.

Comment: You are only using view-image as a class name, not as an element ID, so the :not(#view-image) is unnecessary.  That said, if you change it to :not('#view-image') with quotes around the selector, it works.

Comment: @phari I have another div that I have to use #view-image as id

Comment: **1.** Where is `#view-image`? **2.** Greatly reduce the CSS in your fiddle to the bare minimum so it's easier for us to debug. **3.** It's never a good idea to have a class that's the same as an HTML element (`.img`) nor is it good practice to have IDs and classes that are the same `.view-image`/`#view-image`. This won't cause problems, but it will decrease the maintainability of your code.

Comment: I can't find the `:not` selector anywhere in your jsFiddle link.

Comment: @RocketHazmat this is not true usage.

Comment: @RocketHazmat About line 69 in the CSS. It's a thicket of dense brambles, and there's no good search tool. But that's where it is.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: I did a Crtl+F in the jsFiddle and didn't find anything.

Comment: @RocketHazmat check out css side link 69

Comment: @BramVanroy 1- This selector using at another place. 2- Sorry for that. 3- I will that care of this info.

Comment: @DenizPorsuk: Ah! Ok.  Found it :)

Comment: @Markai Yes that is my problem. Chaining is not working. But w3.org says it should work as this.

Comment: Here w3.org usage http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything is working as is. The chained not selector is working as the `.img` are styled as defined. My friend there is no need to add the tag in the title

Comment: @Huangism I changed .img selector to .img2 tag but still same problem. http://jsfiddle.net/x80vm7y8/8/

Comment: You are quoting the wrong spec - the current recommendation is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation You can see that the comma-separated syntax is currently not allowed. cc @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's there. My browser didn't find it either. I had to copy the CSS to an IDE to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the ID, when you give it a `:not(#xxx)` it gives the selector more specificity and when that happens it overrides the styles from the previous definition which is why you see the wrong styles. Once you remove it it works because the previously defined style is more specific.

You can see this in action using the inspector, it shows the styles being applied with and without the id (remove id part and rerun)

This is the definition you want

```
.viewers .product-exp .view-exp .content .inquiry-form div span.img
```

but when you add the ID, line 69 applies and overrides that.

Simplest thing to do is to add a class to the `#view-image` element and target the `not` to that class, something like

```
.main .content .index-exp .img:not(.new_class):not(.view-image){ /*rest*/ }
```

Comment: I changed #view-image to #test but problem still continues.. So I should not use id selector before class?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason you need to exclude that ID?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk if you use any ID it will override the other styles. If you need to exclude an ID, you can but you need to make sure that the styles defined is what you want because it's going to override your previous styles given the current code.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm using this at another place. But I can change the name of it.

Comment: @Huangism I changed #view-image  id selector to another name and tried. Still background applies to this div from .img. I think that it not right.

Comment: @DenizPorsuk you are missing the point, as I have said if you use ANY ID it will override. The simplest thing to do right now without changing much is to add a class to the element with the ID and change the not to target that class instead of the ID. You can probably just define a class just for the `:not` to target so you won't have this issue

Comment: @Huangism Could you please check. What I'm missing? http://jsfiddle.net/x80vm7y8/10/

Comment: @DenizPorsuk http://jsfiddle.net/x80vm7y8/11/ changed `img2` to `img` in the html and css. I have also updated my answer. It's not working in your fiddle because `.img2` does not have the same styles as `.img`

Comment: @Huangism at my site background is still applying to the div. http://imgur.com/VYcr4OJ

Comment: @DenizPorsuk It's because your previous styles did not have a background set so going down the specificity chain, it will use that background style

Comment: @Huangism god bless you. I appreciated. Do you know a way to remove this effect without using !important

Comment: @DenizPorsuk I am sure there is a way to do it but it's hard to say without seeing an example for this issue. I would suggest you ask another question with a SIMPLIFIED example of your issue as this question and comments are full of stuff