# Chained :not selector does not working for child div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a child div which has been effected by .img class.

Although I insert :not selector for this div as

```
.main .content .index-exp .img:not(.view-image){ /*rest*/ }
```

it is still effecting my div.

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/x80vm7y8/15/ address.

Could it be bug?

My result

[image]

Expected result is

[image]

Comment: `.img` and `.view-image` are not the same element. Therefore, you can't use `:not` in this case.

Comment: How's this question different from [your last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259282/why-does-this-chained-not-selector-not-work)?

Comment: @j08691 If you read it you will see that it is about. Chaining of not: selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the markup provided, it looks like your selector should be:

```
.main .content .index-exp .img img:not(.view-image) {}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kveL8ah2/)

The `img` elements with a class of `.view-image` were descendants of `.img` elements (they didn't contain the `.img` class themselves). You were trying to negate elements with a class of `.view-image` *and* `.img` rather than elements with a class of `.view-image` and a tag *type* of `img`.

Alternatively, the following work work as well:

```
.main .content .index-exp img:not(.view-image) {}
```

Comment: Thats real? Let me check it I spend hours on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.index-exp .img img:not(.view-image){ }
```

(a little faster)